# Couldn't read file LocalFile:

Tags: flutter

In flutter Project I am trying to integrate below plugins

```html
cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.6+3
#  path_provider: ^1.6.5
  url_launcher: ^5.4.2
  image_picker: ^0.6.3+4
  firebase_core: ^0.4.4+3
  cloud_firestore: ^0.13.4+2
  cached_network_image: ^2.0.0
  sqflite: ^1.3.0
  connectivity: ^0.4.8+2
  google_sign_in: ^4.1.4
  google_maps_flutter: ^0.5.24+1
  package_info: ^0.4.0+16
  webview_flutter: ^0.3.19+9
  flutter_bloc: ^3.2.0
  video_player: ^0.10.8+1
  geolocator: ^5.3.0
  device_info: ^0.4.2+1
  share: ^0.6.3+6
  flutter_local_notifications: ^1.2.2
#  firebase_crashlytics: ^0.1.3+3
  android_intent: ^0.3.6+1
  firebase_performance: ^0.3.1+7
  easy_localization: ^2.0.0+1
  battery: ^0.3.1+9
  qrscan: ^0.2.17
  sensors: ^0.4.1+10
#  camera: ^0.5.7+4
  mvc_pattern: ^3.8.0
  flutter_pdfview: ^1.0.1
  cloud_firestore_platform_interface: ^1.1.0
  flutter_cache_store: ^0.7.2
```

I am trying to run the below command

flutter pub get

and getting below errors.

```html
Couldn't read file LocalFile:
'C:\Users\abc\flutter_windows_v1.12.13+hotfix.8-stable\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutt
er_plugin_android_lifecycle-1.0.6\android\src\main\kotlin\io\flutter\plugins\flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle\FlutterAnd
roidLifecyclePlugin.kt' even though it exists. Please verify that this file has read permission and try again.
```

Comment: I'm getting this same error. It seems to be related to plugins I install. Were you able to resolve this?

Comment: In case someone else finds this, my issue was my path name was too long. Had to move flutter sdk to C:\.

Comment: Ok thanks @Screech129